# How can i return an array in php function

Tags: php

I need a return array in function. When i was use that returning this Array ( ):

```
         function menuOlustur($ana_kategoriler){
         global $db;
         $alt_kategori_durum = '';
         $alt_kategori;
             foreach ($ana_kategoriler as $kategori) {
                 $alt_kategori = $db->rawQuery('select * from s_kategoriler where kategori = ' . $kategori['id'] . ' and durum=1 order by sira asc');              
             }
             return $alt_kategori;
     }
```

and i was use this returning one more index in array.

```
         function menuOlustur($ana_kategoriler){
         global $db;
         $alt_kategori_durum = '';
         $alt_kategori;
             foreach ($ana_kategoriler as $kategori) {
                 $alt_kategori[] = $db->rawQuery('select * from s_kategoriler where kategori = ' . $kategori['id'] . ' and durum=1 order by sira asc');              
             }
             return $alt_kategori;
     }
```

My $ana_kategoriler is an array its a calling query like that

```
$ana_k_cek = $db->rawQuery('select id, kategori, adi_' . $dil . ' as adi,link_' . $dil . ' as link from s_kategoriler where m_id=5 and durum=1 order by sira asc ');
```

whats can i do ?

Comment: I see some problems in your code, but also can you post dump od $ana_kategoriler variable before calling menuOlustur function?

In your first code, foreach have no sense, as $alt_kategori will be query ouput for last "id" from your parameter $ana_kategoriler

Your second code is better, but please replace  $alt_kategori; with  $alt_kategori = array();

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** fixed query, should not be kategori = 1,2,3,4, but kategory IN(1,2,3,4)

I suggest to change your code to:

```
function menuOlustur($ana_kategoriler){
    global $db;
    /* first - collect all ids */
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($ana_kategoriler as $kategori) {
        $ids[] = $kategori['id'];         
    }
    /* return empty array if there is no ids, or return result of single query matching all results with given ids */
    return count($ids) > 0 ? $db->rawQuery('select * from s_kategoriler where kategori IN( ' . implode(",",$ids)  . ') AND durum=1 order by sira asc') : array();   
}
```

Comment: `kategori = ' . implode(",",$ids)` won't work. It will create an invalid query: `kategori = 1,2,3,4,5...`. if you want to select from a comma separated list, you need to use `WHERE kategori IN (1,2,3,4,...) `.